# MySQL connection to Springboot

Tags: mysql, eclipse, spring-boot

I looked into similar issues and tried to do different options as mentioned in the prior threads, but not able to fix it. I have the error below, can somebody help me to fix this issue.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.2.11.RELEASE)

2020-12-08 15:05:30.602  INFO 11076 --- [           main] c.p.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : Starting ConferenceDemoApplication on DESKTOP-3RN8P39 with PID 11076 (C:\Users\tania\Downloads\conference-demo\conference-demo\target\classes started by tania in C:\Users\tania\Downloads\conference-demo)
2020-12-08 15:05:30.607  INFO 11076 --- [           main] c.p.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-08 15:05:32.039  INFO 11076 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-08 15:05:32.162  INFO 11076 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 109ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-08 15:05:33.208  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-08 15:05:33.220  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-08 15:05:33.221  INFO 11076 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-12-08 15:05:33.339  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-08 15:05:33.339  INFO 11076 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2655 ms
2020-12-08 15:05:33.595  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-08 15:05:33.655  INFO 11076 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.22.Final
2020-12-08 15:05:33.775  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2020-12-08 15:05:33.866  INFO 11076 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-08 15:05:34.392  INFO 11076 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-12-08 15:05:34.406  WARN 11076 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.mysqlDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
2020-12-08 15:05:34.409  WARN 11076 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2020-12-08 15:05:34.410  INFO 11076 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-12-08 15:05:34.413  INFO 11076 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-12-08 15:05:34.416  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-08 15:05:34.426  INFO 11076 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-08 15:05:34.432 ERROR 11076 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.ConferenceDemoApplication.main(ConferenceDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.mysqlDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.mysqlDialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.mysqlDialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Pom.xml application properties

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.2.11.RELEASE
 

com.example
demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.mysqlDialect`. This class name is misspelled. It should be `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` in your application.properties file. Alternatively, instead of explicitly configuring the dialect, let Hibernate automatically detect the dialect.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying different options to get rid of this error, but it appears that the issue is with the mapping. Below are the model outputs, need your help in resolving this issue.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.2.11.RELEASE)

2020-12-09 18:16:25.136  INFO 16144 --- [           main] c.p.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : Starting ConferenceDemoApplication on DESKTOP-3RN8P39 with PID 16144 (C:\Users\tania\Downloads\conference-demo\conference-demo\target\classes started by tania in C:\Users\tania\Downloads\conference-demo)
2020-12-09 18:16:25.140  INFO 16144 --- [           main] c.p.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-09 18:16:26.448  INFO 16144 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-09 18:16:26.577  INFO 16144 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 114ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-09 18:16:27.536  INFO 16144 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-09 18:16:27.552  INFO 16144 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-09 18:16:27.552  INFO 16144 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-12-09 18:16:27.676  INFO 16144 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-09 18:16:27.676  INFO 16144 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2437 ms
2020-12-09 18:16:27.898  INFO 16144 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-09 18:16:27.946  INFO 16144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.22.Final
2020-12-09 18:16:28.062  INFO 16144 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-12-09 18:16:28.154  INFO 16144 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-09 18:16:28.501  INFO 16144 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-12-09 18:16:28.517  INFO 16144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-12-09 18:16:28.827  WARN 16144 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.models.Session.speakers references an unknown entity: java.util.List
2020-12-09 18:16:28.827  INFO 16144 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-12-09 18:16:28.854  INFO 16144 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-12-09 18:16:28.854  INFO 16144 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-09 18:16:28.863  INFO 16144 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-09 18:16:28.872 ERROR 16144 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.models.Session.speakers references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.ConferenceDemoApplication.main(ConferenceDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.models.Session.speakers references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1823) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Model1**

```
    package com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.models;
    
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Entity(name="sessions")
    public class Session {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long session_id;
        @Column(name="session_name", nullable = false)
        private String session_name;
        @Column(name="session_description", nullable = false)
        private String session_description;
        @Column(name="session_length", nullable = false)`enter code here`
        private Integer session_length;
    
    
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
                name="session_speakers",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="session_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="speaker_id")
        )
    
    
        private List<Speakers> speakers;
        public Session(){
    
        }
    
        public List<Speakers> getSpeakers() {
            return speakers;
        }
    
        public void setSpeakers(List<Speakers> speakers) {
            this.speakers = speakers;
        }
    
        public Long getSession_id() {
            return session_id;
        }
    
        public void setSession_id(Long session_id) {
            this.session_id = session_id;
        }
    
        public String getSession_name() {
            return session_name;
        }
    
        public void setSession_name(String session_name) {
            this.session_name = session_name;
        }
    
        public String getSession_description() {
            return session_description;
        }
    
        public void setSession_description(String session_description) {
            this.session_description = session_description;
        }
    
        public Integer getSession_length() {
            return session_length;
        }
    
        public void setSession_length(Integer session_length) {
            this.session_length = session_length;
        }
    }
```

**Model2**

```
    package com.pluralsight.conferencedemo.models;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Entity(name="speakers")
    public class Speakers {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long speaker_id;
        @Column(name="first_name", nullable = false)
        private String first_name;
        @Column(name="last_name", nullable = false)
        private String last_name;
        @Column(name="title", nullable = false)
        private String title;
        @Column(name="company", nullable = false)
        private String company;
        @Column(name="speaker_bio", nullable = false)
        private String speaker_bio;
    
    
        private byte[] speaker_photo;
    
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy= "speakers")
        private List<Session> session;
    
        public Speakers(){
    
        }
    
        public byte[] getSpeaker_photo() {
            return speaker_photo;
        }
    
        public void setSpeaker_photo(byte[] speaker_photo) {
            this.speaker_photo = speaker_photo;
        }
    
        public List<Session> getSession() {
            return session;
        }
    
        public void setSession(List<Session> session) {
            this.session = session;
        }
    
        public Long getSpeaker_id() {
            return speaker_id;
        }
    
        public void setSpeaker_id(Long speaker_id) {
            this.speaker_id = speaker_id;
        }
    
        public String getFirst_name() {
            return first_name;
        }
    
        public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }
    
        public String getLast_name() {
            return last_name;
        }
    
        public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }
    
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    
        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }
    
        public void setCompany(String company) {
            this.company = company;
        }
    
        public String getSpeaker_bio() {
            return speaker_bio;
        }
    
        public void setSpeaker_bio(String speaker_bio) {
            this.speaker_bio = speaker_bio;
        }
    }
```